# how to monitor the close event of a JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, jdialog, windowlistener

I have got a tricky problem. I need to pop a confirm message box for user to decide close or not when someone click the close sign on the right upper corner of the window. But It doesn't work. Whatever you choose in the pop message box , the dialog will always be closed. But the same logic works fine when I create a JFrame.

Below is my code in my netbeans IED. 
I just use a WindowAdpter to catch the close event, plz igore the dummy code generated by neatbean.

Thanks.

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class TestClosingDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public TestClosingDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();


        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you need to close？", "Tip", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (a == 0) {  
                    System.out.println("yes " + a);
                    System.exit(0);  //close 
                } else if (a==1) {
                    System.out.println("no " + a);
                } 
            }
       });
    }

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestClosingDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestClosingDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestClosingDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestClosingDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the dialog */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TestClosingDialog dialog = new TestClosingDialog(new JFrame(), true);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` to `setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING);`

This will require you to manually `dispose` of the dialog.  Depending on your needs, you would simply need to change `System.exit(0);` to `dispose();`

I would, personally, advise against extending directly from a top level container like `JDialog`, but that's just me.

I prefer to use, something like, a `JPanel` that has a helper method that can display an dialog.  This method would create the dialog and add the panel to it, for example

Comment: thanks a lot, buddy. it works. Yeah , I do the same way in my usual code using a JPanel as you suggested. This is just a test demo. Really appreciate, you have saved my time.

Comment: btw, do you have any ideas on how to package and distribute a swing desktop application. I have finished a swing project in netbeans, and now I need to package and distribute it. I use mysql database. Can I package it as a exe install file or something? So that the users can just install it like the normal windows software even though they have no JRE environment on their computers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's numrous ways, obviously, start with a clean and build.  It will output the binaries in the dist directory.  You could create an installer, something like [izPack](http://izpack.org/), which is open source, might suit for starters.  You could also trake a look at [JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html).  It's not an absolute requirement that you create a `exe` file, I personally do most of the time as I tend to have `jar` setup to be opened by `7Zip` by default.  I use [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html)

Comment: Installing without a JRE previously installed is tricky.  I think something like Install4J can do and there might be others that will let you bundle a JRE with the installer/application. Best thing to do is look around

Comment: And how about the database? any ideas on how to migrate?

Comment: That's a problem, I assume you're using a database server (and not embedded/standalone/single user - not sure if MySQL can do this).  You would need an installer that was capable of running additional executables.  Most can, at some level.  Depending on what your needs are, I might consider a using a single user database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) which has the capacity to run in embedded mode (without the need to a server)